# CSS3 :not negation pseudo-class not fully supported by Firefox?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use the CSS3 :not pseudo class as defined in the specification. According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is
>   a functional notation taking a simple
>   selector (excluding the negation
>   pseudo-class itself) as an argument.
>   It represents an element that is not
>   represented by its argument

So I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
p:not(.class1, .class2)
```

But it does not seem to work in Safari or Firefox, which are supposed to have FULL support for this selector.

It does work when the argument is a single selector, for example:

Here is an example showing the issue: [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xr2Ap/)

```
p:not(.class1)
```

According to [this](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/) blog post, this author suggests that you should be able to specify multiple selectors as the argument.

Also according to this [CSS3 SitePoint Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-not), Firefox, Safari and Chrome have FULL support for the :not selector.

Am I misinterpreting the specification or do browsers actually only have partial support for this selector?

Comment: `.class1, .class2` is not a simple selector, and by definition `:not(X)` only accepts simple selectors as arguments.

Comment: That blog post is wrong. If Firefox supported multiple selectors in a single negation, it doesn't anymore, and that behavior was a bug.

Comment: @BoltClock Correct - tried it out in FF3.6 and FF4 and it won't work so the guy must be wrong, also blog date is 25 August 2008 when css3 was still a baby.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In CSS the comma (`,`) separates selectors. It's not a selector itself so it can't be used inside a selector. So depending of if you want to apply the rule to

- paragraphs that are not `.class1` and paragraphs that are not `.class2`,
- paragraphs that have neither `.class1` nor `class2` or
- <s>paragraphs that don't have `.class1` **and** `.class2`</s>

it's

```
p:not(.class1), p:not(.class2) {
}
```

or

```
p:not(.class1):not(.class2) {
}
```

or

```
p:not(.class1.class2) {
}
```

BTW, IMHO it's better to avoid `:not` if possible and in this case, for example, have a general rule that applies to all `p`s (with the properties you want to set in the `:not`rule) and one that applies to ones with the class and overrides the properties of the first rule if necessary.

Comment: p:not(.class1.class2) will not work. That is not valid markup.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah syntax/code/whatever - I tend to confuse the terms often. English not my native language :)

Comment: Still does not seem to work, see: http://jsfiddle.net/yw3fE/ - I want all P tags that have either .po or .no to be excluded.

Comment: Ok it seems that your second example has the desired effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can *chain* them (listing them didn't work for me either)...

```
p:not(.class1):not(.class2) {
  ...  
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ddsdv/).

Works for me in Chrome 10.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with:

```
p:not(.class1), p:not(.class2) {
}
```

Because, it is same as calling `p {}` (when you separate by ",", it means union). The first effected tags set (the p tags without the `class1` class) unions with the second effected tags set (p tags without the `class2` class).